# for loop working in CMD prompt but not in batch file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I have this code working on my CMD promt (with one % instead %%) but when I executed it through a .bat file it isn't working.

```
for /f "tokens=5 delims=: " %%G in ('netsh interface IPv4 show dnsserver "Ethernet 2" ^| findstr /C:"Servidores DNS configurados estáticamente"') DO (Echo %%G)
```

I'm trying to do a .bat that swaps my main and secondary DNS for another two. I was trying with something like this:

```
@echo off  
cls  
color A
cls

SET DNS1=46.101.36.120
SET DNS2=46.101.149.135
SET DNSGoogle1=8.8.8.8
SET DNSGoogle2=8.8.4.4
SET NAME=Ethernet 2


for /f "tokens=5 delims=: " %%G in ('netsh interface IPv4 show dnsserver "%NAME%" ^| findstr /C:"Servidores DNS configurados estáticamente"') DO IF %DNSGoogle1%==%%G (goto netflixDNS) ELSE (goto googleDNS)


:netflixDNS
echo "Netflix DNS"
netsh interface ipv4 delete dnsserver "%NAME%" all
netsh interface ip set dnsservers "%NAME%" static %DNS1%
netsh interface ip add dnsservers "%NAME%" %DNS2% index=2
ipconfig /flushdns
PAUSE
EXIT

:googleDNS
echo "Google DNS"
netsh interface ipv4 delete dnsserver "%NAME%" all
netsh interface ip set dnsservers "%NAME%" static %DNSGoogle1%
netsh interface ip add dnsservers "%NAME%" %DNSGoogle2% index=2
ipconfig /flushdns
PAUSE
EXIT
```

For some reason my `FOR`isn't working...

Comment: That's because of `á` character. I would simply shorten the text to `Servidores DNS configurados est`.

Answer (score 3):

Although solved by [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom)'s comment, this question requires some explanation: flagrant [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case. To avoid this kind of mojibake, run your batch script under the same code page which it's saved in: supposedly `CP1252` if saved in ANSI encoding (`notepad`).

For proof:

- save a mix of [French, German, Portuguese and Spanish accented letters](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/index.html) as a plain text file

  - in `CP850` (DOS Western Europe) encoding, and another file
  - in `CP1252` (Windows Western) encoding;
- display those files under different encodings to show mojibake-affected characters.

Please do not insert next code snippet to a batch script. **Copy & paste** it in an open command line window:

```
chcp 850>NUL
echo áéíóúüýñäëêöã  850>ew-850.txt
chcp 1252>NUL
echo áéíóúüýñäëêöã 1252>ew1252.txt
for %G in (437 850 1252) do @chcp %G&>NUL timeout /T 1 &findstr "^" "ew*.txt"
```

**Output**:

```
==> chcp 850>NUL

==> echo áéíóúüýñäëêöã  850>ew-850.txt

==> chcp 1252>NUL

==> echo áéíóúüýñäëêöã 1252>ew1252.txt

==> for %G in (437 850 1252) do @chcp %G&>NUL timeout /T 1 &findstr "^" "ew*.txt"
Active code page: 437
ew-850.txt:áéíóúü∞ñäëêö╞  850
ew1252.txt:ßΘφ≤·ⁿ²±ΣδΩ÷π 1252
Active code page: 850
ew-850.txt:áéíóúüýñäëêöã  850
ew1252.txt:ßÚÝ¾·³²±õÙÛ÷Ò 1252
Active code page: 1252
ew-850.txt: ‚¡¢£ì¤„‰ˆ”Æ  850
ew1252.txt:áéíóúüýñäëêöã 1252

==>
```

Another example with (incomplete assortment of) [Czech and Slovak accented letters](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/czechslovak.html) and Central Europe encodings (code pages `CP852` and `CP1250`):

```
chcp 852>NUL
echo áéíóúůýňěščřž  852>ee-852.txt
chcp 1250>NUL
echo áéíóúůýňěščřž 1250>ee1250.txt
for %G in (437 852 1250) do @chcp %G&>NUL timeout /T 1 &findstr "^" "ee*.txt"
```

**Edit**: Another extra illustrative example (copy&paste into a `cmd` window).

```
ECHO OFF
chcp 850>NUL
echo echo %~0 [áéíóúüýñäëêöã] 850>ew-850.bat
chcp 1252>NUL
echo echo %~0 [áéíóúüýñäëêöã]1252>ew1252.bat
chcp 850>NUL
ew-850.bat
ew1252.bat
chcp 1252>NUL
ew-850.bat
ew1252.bat
ECHO ON
```

**Output**:

```
==> ECHO OFF
chcp 850>NUL
echo echo %~0 [áéíóúüýñäëêöã] 850>ew-850.bat
chcp 1252>NUL
echo echo %~0 [áéíóúüýñäëêöã]1252>ew1252.bat
chcp 850>NUL
ew-850.bat
ew-850.bat [áéíóúüýñäëêöã] 850
ew1252.bat
ew1252.bat [ßÚÝ¾·³²±õÙÛ÷Ò]1252
chcp 1252>NUL
ew-850.bat
ew-850.bat [ ‚¡¢£ì¤„‰ˆ”Æ] 850
ew1252.bat
ew1252.bat [áéíóúüýñäëêöã]1252
ECHO ON

==>
```